# Mysql log table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, partitioning

I have a logging table that contains 3 fields

Id action time

The time column is 11 digit integer. Our goal is that each month the logs of the prior month will be deleted. It is possible to do with a simple query, but since the table is getting pretty big, the delete query is quite heavy as well. I was thinking about adding an index on the time column, but i don't want to slow down the logging process  only for the cleaning of the table. I was considering partition by month but wont it slow down inserts as well? And moreover, when i tried to partition by 
from_unixtime(month(time_created)) i got a not allows partition function error.

What are the best practices to do such as operation? Thank you very mich

Comment: Check http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for details of such partitioning schema. With partitioning the inserts go to a smaller table so it should not be slower. But you maybe do not need it yet - how many rows are in that table? (how many are inserted during a month?) Adding the index you need to make deletes faster makes sense if you delete only a relatively small part of the table (usually the 20% is stated as a reasonable limit for index usage), if you delete half of the rows then the index won't be used anyway.

Comment: Or if you maybe delete 90% of the table, then copying 10% instead to a new table and dropping the old one would be fastest.

Comment: Hi, the idea is basically keeping 2 months in our database: this month and the month before. It pretty much removing half of the table in the end of every month, and we are talking about 500000 rows approximately, so index is out of the question according to what you say.

Comment: Yes, MySQL won't use the index unless you really force to it, because it does not know that the rows are clustered by time unless you base the primary key on the time (and use InnoDB).  For removing half of the table partitioning sounds like a good idea. Another question is if you need to have the logs in MySQL at all, do you need to search them using SQL and join them to other data? Wouldn't writting them to text files be more effective? (simpler structure, backup and management).

Comment: Writes to text files arent slower than the mysql? Basically, the logs are in the db just for the good order of things. So you would suggest partitioning by month?

Comment: Why would writting to files be slower? Text files do not have any complex structure, indexes or anything, no need for rollbacks and extra synchronization. All this is overhead on the DB side. If you write to a file, OS can decide when to flush its buffers to disk, no double buffering and such. The only drawback is that if you write something and there is for example power outage, you cannot tell if the entire buffer will be flushed etc. but all this is part of why DB is not the fastest way to store data.

Comment: Or just set a cron job or MySQL event to delete one day's records (from two months ago) on a daily basis every 24 hours at 3 in the morning (or when your system isn't busy)? Shouldn't be too much overhead then! Personally though, I'd still archive them somewhere - with storage being cheap, some dusty old server could hold a good chunk of data.

Comment: Use the partitionmaint link and (for 1-month's data) have 33 daily partitions or 6 weekly partitions.  Partitioning is picky about what `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` you use.  `INT` would work, too, but the link does not give the details.  Lop off a day or week once a day or week.  (No good reason to lop off 1 of 2 months.)